# QGIS "ERROR" written in all fields in attribute table of a View coming from PostgreSQL/PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, sql-view, postgresql-10

I have a table of around 800000 records with *POINT* geometry in PostgreSQL/PostGIS. When I directly open the table in QGIS, the attribute table opens fine and the fields are populated.

But when I open the *View* of same exact table, "ERROR" is populated in all fields in the attribute table.

If I reduce the size of the table or reduce columns then the attribute table opens fine for a *View* as well.

I dont know what is the problem. Is there some memory limitations for a view in QGIS?

[image: This is what attribute table of a view of same tables look like.]

Comment: I definitely think this should NOT be closed. It contains valuable information with the answer below!

Answer (score 4):

Solved it. Memory was not an issue. QGIS was not able to get a unique key of that view. Placed that key in the start and it worked fine.